# why $\frac{t + t^2}{(1 + t)^2} \sim t + t^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

While doing my physics homework where answer is given I found that correct answer could be obtained with simplification

$\frac{t + t^2}{(1 + t)^2} \sim t + t^2,$

when $t\ll 1$. My attempt was:

$\frac{t+t^2}{t^2 + 2t + 1} \to \frac{t}{2t + 1}$

Why I was wrong?

Comment: To make sense of the question, you should add something like $t \to 0$ or $t \to \infty$ or $t \to 17$.

Comment: I guess $t\to 0$, Then $(1+t)^2\to 1$ which means that the fraction and $t+t^2$ goes to zero equally fast. Exact definition for $f(x)\sim g(x)$ is that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 1$.

Comment: The fact that $t$ is much less than $1$ does not mean that $t<\varepsilon$ for a positive $\varepsilon$. In other words, $t$ does not necessarily approach $0$. They were implying that adding $t$ to $1$ is insignificant.

Comment: Note that the solution given in your book is also wrong, there should be a "$-$" in front of $t^2$.

Comment: @GeorgSaliba is 1 not a positive '\epsilon'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\frac{ t + t^2}{(1+t)^2} = t \frac{ 1+t}{(1+t)^2}= \frac{t}{1+t} = 1 - \frac{ 1}{1+t}$.

Since $t << 1$ we can use Taylor Series around $t=0$, if we assume $t \ge 0$. Then we find
$$f(t) =\frac{t+t^2}{(1+t)^2} \sim f(0) + f'(0)t + \frac{1}{2} f''(0)t^2 = 0 + t-t^2$$
Since we have $f'(t) =\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}$ and $f''(t) = - \frac{2}{(1+t)^3}$.

You were 'wrong' by just simplifying the equation, as you did not approximate the function.

Comment: $t<<1$ not $t<<\varepsilon$, so you can't apply the Maclaurin series.

Comment: Thank you, now I see my mistake.

Comment: @GeorgSaliba You are right that t<<1 and not t << \varepsilon, but in my Physics undergrad t << 1 always meant that t is close to 0.

Comment: Apparently the correct answer to fit the physics part isn't $t-t^2$, rather $t+t^2$ according to the post. But if we're talking Special Relativity, then you're most probably right.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

To make a sense, see this picture
  every function around zero has slope $+1$

but $t-t^2$ is more like to $\frac{t+t^2}{(1+t)^2}$ when $t<<1$
$$\frac{t+t^2}{(1+t)^2}=\frac{t}{1+t} \sim t(1-t)$$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know the geometric sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$

$\frac{t+t^2}{(1+t)^2} = \frac{t(1+t)}{(1+t)^2} = \frac{t}{1+t} = t(1-t+t^2-t^3+t^4+...) = t - t^2+t^3-t^4+t^5...$

provided $|t|<1$.

So your solution is wrong.